# Conditional copy and paste excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste a certain value from a cell in one sheet matching a range in another workbook. The code runs fine, doesn't give any run-time errors, but will not paste in the range declared in the other workbook. Code below

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()
    Dim dest As Worksheet
    
    Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VCP Plan")
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("D:D")
    
    Dim OpenWorkBook As Variant
    OpenWorkBook = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")
    
    If OpenWorkBook <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open (OpenWorkBook)
    End If
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "26ASA00015D007" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Copy Destination:=dest.Range("E3")
        End If
    Next cell            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your description and your code which workbook/worksheet you want to compare and copy, and which workbook/worksheet you want to copy to.

You'll need to be more specific

I've made a guess at what you are trying to do.  If I've got it wrong, simply adjust the references to suit

Something like

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()
    Dim wbSource as Workbook
    Dim wsSource as Worksheet
    Dim rSource as Range
    Dim wbDest as Workbook
    Dim wsDest as Worksheet
    Dim rDest as Range

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook ' Are you sure?
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("VCP Plan")
    Set rDest = ws.Range("E3")

    Dim OpenWorkBook As Variant
    OpenWorkBook = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")
    
    If OpenWorkBook <> False Then
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(OpenWorkBook) 
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("NameOfSourceSheet")

    Dim cell As Range
    With wsSource
        ' Column D from row 1 to last used row
        Set rSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
    End With
    

    For Each cell In rSource
        If cell.Value = "26ASA00015D007" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Copy Destination:=rDest
            ' You probably don't want to overwrite each time, so
            Set rDest = rDest.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next cell            
End Sub
```